Is there a tool in Windows 10 that I can use to draw an arrow in any direction?
It seems hard to do this in mspaint although there's some workaround. I don't want to use a third-party tool, just want a tool accompanied by Windows 10 or can be downloaded from Microsoft.

Yes, its called a mouse. You click the paint tool, then hold the left button down while moving the mouse such that it draws an arrow. But in all seriousness, mspaint is not the best paint editing program. Tools like paint.net are far more suitable to do graphical things, and if you just want to draw an arrow as a way to point things out on your screenshot, use GreenShot instead. You can make a screencapture, open it in its own image editor, select the arrow painting tool and just draw an arrow. Windows Snipping tool could also have this.

@LPChip That mouse only draws a line without an arrow. paint.net and GreenShot are third-party tools. Windows Snipping tool doesn't have an arrow tool, either. I recall I could draw an arrow in old version of Windows but now this simple task becomes an impossible mission.

Then the answer is: not possible. Note that greenshot is available in the windows store, and I believe paint.net could be too. Greenshot is also available through Microsoft's chocolatery.

@William or can be downloaded from Microsoft  - paint.net satisfies your criteria

@Paul I'd like an app developed by Microsoft.
